# How to connect virtual machines from different proxmoxes?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, vlan, proxmox

I have cluster of 3 proxmoxes and I want to create shared network to connect virtual machines from different physical machines. Virtual machines should be able to see other machines from their network, but not the physical machines and not the other computers from external network. Virtual machines will get the internet through NAT. I don't have switch supporting vlan. 
What is the best solution to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tinc](https://www.tinc-vpn.org/) vpn or [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source.html) to achieve that (of course only in case of all your VMs has WAN connection). Both are quite stable solutions. Also both has quite wide range of how-to's for almost every OS.

Comment: > of course only in case of all your VMs has WAN connection <
What do you mean?

Comment: @devalone In some scenarios, some of Virtual Machines shouldn't access to internet(WAN). Even in that case, you can still connect them into your VPN (through your Proxmox hosts) but that is little bit complex task. Building VPN won't be a problem if all of them access internet(with or without NAT).

Comment: Where should I place OpenVPN server in this case? On one of three proxmoxes?

Comment: @devalone you can use one of your VMs as vpn server or you can create a dedicated new vm. System requirements are quite low for both. 1GB RAM would be overly enough

Comment: but, how to make isolated network in this case? VMs shouldn't see physical machines.

Comment: @devalone maybe you should check concept of VPN. It's virtual private network. So in that network all traffic is encrypted and isolated between just VPN peers not proxmox host(unless you add them into VPN). So you will have totally isolated, secure network. Just don't add WAN(internet) route at vpn server If don't want internet access at your peers in the network(i meant internet access through your VPN server)

Answer (score 0):

You can use open virtual switch (inside in proxmox) with vxlan support throughout GRE tunnel across virtual switch or enumerate a different subnet for VMs.